# Google Apps Script SOAP response is encoded. How/where to add base64decode to see the response as xml

Tags: soap, google-apps-script, base64

Below is my working Google apps script SOAP API envelop call. It works to connect ok and as you can see below it returns a response, but my response is encoded. How/where to add a bit to do a Base64decode to see the XML that is returned instead of the string of characters?  I am totally new to SOAP API and still a newbie to apps script too. Thanks!

```
function getData() { 
var webservice = ‘https://someplace.com/services/stuff/’;

var xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://someurlhere.com">'
+   '<soapenv:Header/>'
+   '<soapenv:Body>'
+ '<ser:getReportXML soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> '
+    '<in0 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +  userid + '</in0> '
+    '<in1 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' + password + '</in1> '
+    '<in2 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' + startDate + '</in2> '
+    '<in3 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' + endDate + '</in3> '
+ '</ser:getReportXML> '
+   '</soapenv:Body>'
+' </soapenv:Envelope>'

var options = {  
  headers: {"SOAPAction" :"https://someplace.com/services/stuff/"},
  method: "post",
  contentType: "text/xml",
  payload: xml,
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
};

var serviceaddress = webservice;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceaddress, options);
Logger.log(response);

};
```

It returns an encoded string in the response, but I want to see the actual XML results:

```
[19-01-31 11:46:02:122 PST] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:getReportXMLResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1=" http://someurlhere.com "><getReportXMLReturn xsi:type="soapenc:base64Binary" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">WMui8xyxcPQXmZgSerdPd94bwWxGsAMgdmVyc2lvbj0iFRxlTSerdgiPz4NCg0KPQFET0NUW
```

I am trying to get the response output to look like xml and not a string of characters

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE ETRANS PUBLIC "-//Something//ethings DTD//EN" "https://www.url.com/dtd/ethings_1_0.dtd">

<ETRANS>
<USER ID="AABB1122" USER_NAME="Smith, John" DATE="2019-02-01 09:41:45" DEPT_ID=""/>
</ETRANS>
```

So I figured out that my response does have the encoded body of the XML, but it also has all these extra bits in the response before the actual encoded data, so the decoder fails as it doesn't know what to do with this bit shown here at the beginning of the response

```
[19-01-31 11:46:02:122 PST] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:getReportXMLResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1=" http://someurlhere.com "><getReportXMLReturn xsi:type="soapenc:base64Binary" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
```

and a few more bits at the bottom that are like some closing of the above bits. Is there something I need to pass in my request to have the SOAP request only return the character string and not these extra bits that look like it is putting the "envelope" around the encoded data it is sending back?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about ``It returns an encoded string in the response, but I want to see the actual XML results:``. 2. What kind of relation does your script have to your issue? If I misunderstand your question, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I added a bit above to clarify what I am trying to figure out how to "decode" the response from the character string to the actual xml. I hope that helps make it more clear. Also, I am not sure if I need to change something in my SOAP request to achieve this, so that is why I included my code.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: So I figured out that my response does have the encoded body of the XML, but is also has all these extra bits in the response before the actual encoded data

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. I don't know if there is a "better" way to do this, but if you see what I did maybe you might share that "better" way. So I added the "NEW BIT" lines below. I had to get rid of the SOAP Envelop in order to decode the base64 bit. The only way I could figure out in Google Apps Script was to save the response as a file as that seemed to "magically" take the SOAP away. So then I had to get the base64 bit that was left that was in the MyTestFile file I created into a text string and decode/convert that and it created the xml I was looking for. I hope this can help someone else out.

```
function getData() { 
    var webservice = ‘https://someplace.com/services/stuff/’;
    var newDocName = 'MyTestFile'

    var xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://someurlhere.com">'
    +   '<soapenv:Header/>'
    +   '<soapenv:Body>'
    + '<ser:getReportXML soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> '
    +    '<in0 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +  userid + '</in0> '
    +    '<in1 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' + password + '</in1> '
    +    '<in2 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' + startDate + '</in2> '
    +    '<in3 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' + endDate + '</in3> '
    + '</ser:getReportXML> '
    +   '</soapenv:Body>'
    +' </soapenv:Envelope>'

    var options = {  
      headers: {"SOAPAction" :""},
      method: "post",
      contentType: "text/xml",
      payload: xml,
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };

    var serviceaddress = webservice;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceaddress, options).getContentText();
    //Logger.log(response);

    //NEW BIT BEGINS HERE THAT DECODED THE RESPONSE

    var blob = DriveApp.createFile('dummy',response, 'text/html').getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: newDocName,
      convert: true,
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'
    };

    var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource,blob);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
    var text = doc.getBody().getText();

    var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(text,Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);  // This was a byte array
    var decodedstr = Utilities.newBlob(decoded).getDataAsString()  // This was the xml I was looking for
    Logger.log(decodedstr);
    //NEW BIT ENDS HERE 
};
```